# How to get the domain name for a public key?

Tags: publickey

Using the Bonfida APIs, you can do a reverse lookup as follows:

```
import { performReverseLookup } from "@bonfida/spl-name-service";

// Public key of bonfida.sol
const domainKey = new PublicKey("Crf8hzfthWGbGbLTVCiqRqV5MVnbpHB1L9KQMd6gsinb");

const domainName = await performReverseLookup(connection, domainKey); // bonfida
```

In practice, this is returning an "invalid account name" error for user public keys. Is there an intermediary step to convert from a user's public key to their naming account public key first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an alternative way to get all the domain names owned by a public key:

```
import { Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { NAME_PROGRAM_ID } from "@bonfida/spl-name-service";

export async function findOwnedNameAccountsForUser(
  connection: Connection,
  userAccount: PublicKey
): Promise<PublicKey[]> {
  const filters = [
    {
      memcmp: {
        offset: 32,
        bytes: userAccount.toBase58(),
      },
    },
  ];
  const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(NAME_PROGRAM_ID, {
    filters,
  });
  return accounts.map((a) => a.publicKey);
}
```

Comment: I used `getAllDomains` from Bonfida but this is much better, ty!

Answer (score 1):

Was able to figure it out - TL;DR you need to add a call for `getAllDomains` first.

So,

```
const pubKey = new PublicKey('some-public-key');
const domains = await getAllDomains(connection, pubKey);
const reqs = domains.map((x) => performReverseLookup(connection, x));
const resolvedNames = await Promise.all(reqs);
```

Answer (score -1):

On solscan.io you can find Domains based on the Public Key provided.

See this example;

https://solscan.io/account/GaxVqiQyJKQDRu6H4pfy9V6Xq19pHGr6HQKDQDv911Y4#domains

Comment: I'm curious on how to do it via the API :)